# Plot : Interpret the output

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying a simple plot in Octave:

```
>> y = [ 1 1 1 ; 0 1 0]
y =

   1   1   1
   0   1   0

>> plot(.1:.1:.2,y,'b')
```

I get the below output:

I cannot understand the plot output - where are values of y ie 1,1,1,0,1,0 plotted and why there is a diagonal line rendered?

[image]

And when I try diff combinations, like:

```
>> y = [ 1 0 0 ; 0 1 0]
y =

   1   0   0
   0   1   0

>> plot(.1:.1:.2,y,'b')
```

Th plotting is as below:

[image]

```
>> y = [ 1 0 0 ; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1]
y =

   1   0   0
   0   1   0
   0   0   1

>> plot(.1:.1:.3,y,'b')
```

[image]

How can we infer plot chart from the values of y that are mentioned to be plotted?

Comment: No ofense, but it looks like you dont have any idea of what you are doing!

Comment: Well I am trying to learn basics of plotting and just a beginner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How the plot function works: You give some x values and the same amount of y values and it will plot them.

However, you can also give `plot` multiple y arrays, so you can plot more than 1 function with the same x values.

In your first plot you are plotting 3 functions:

```
plot([0.1 0.2], [1 0])
plot([0.1 0.2], [1 1])
plot([0.1 0.2], [0 1])
```

In the figure there are 3 plots, however, your axis are too tight and you cant see them, as one is a horizontal line and the other one a vertical line. if you write `axis([0 0.3 -1 2])` you will see the three lines. The same thing happen sin your other plots, you are drawing 3 y values for each x value.

I recommend you to stop forcing the color of the plot (the `'b'` part tells the plot to draw everything in blue) so you can clearly see that there are 3 plots there.

So for example if you write:

```
y= [ 1 0 0 ; 0 1 0];
plot(.1:.1:.2,y)
axis([0 0.3 -1 2])
```

You will see the three plots with different color each as:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

> If x is a vector and y is a matrix, then the columns (or rows) of y are plotted versus x. (using whichever combination matches, with columns tried first.)

In the first case you are plotting [1;0] which is the diagonal, [1;1] which is hidden by the axis and [1;0] again